# Default STARTUP TCP probe failed 1 time consecutively for container "develop" on port 8080. The instance was not started

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, .net-core, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to use a net core 2.1 app in docker, using cloud functions on GCP, but I recieved this message:

> Default STARTUP TCP probe failed 1 time consecutively for container "-develop" on port 8080. The instance was not started.

The app show the logs

> "the app is listening now in port 8080"

And this is my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1-bionic

WORKDIR /app

COPY WebAPI ./WebAPI
COPY Core ./Core
COPY Server.sln /app

RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out WebAPI/WebAPI.csproj

WORKDIR /app/WebAPI

ENV ASPNETCORE_hostBuilder__reloadConfigOnChange=false

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["dotnet", "run", "--urls", "http://*:8080"]
```

When the app wait 3 minutes to a response, the docker failed.

Someone explain me whats can be the error in docker?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error with deploying my react app on cloud run. For me adding `ENV HOST 0.0.0.0` in my Dockerfile solved the issue.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1-bionic

WORKDIR /app

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0

COPY WebAPI ./WebAPI
COPY Core ./Core
COPY Server.sln /app

RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out WebAPI/WebAPI.csproj

WORKDIR /app/WebAPI

ENV ASPNETCORE_hostBuilder__reloadConfigOnChange=false

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["dotnet", "run", "--urls", "http://*:8080"]
```

Try it